# Unity3D, пластилиновая модель

Tags: unity3d, объекты, моделирование

Задача: необходимо сделать шар, такой, чтобы если на него уронили металлический объект, то шар под действием силы тяжести несколько деформировался и сохранял свою деформацию. Действие происходит в Unity.

Я так понял что сама Unity умеет создавать только металлические объекты(или делать металлическими импортируемые модели), и максимум как я могу приблизиться к цели это подобрать(или создать) какой - нибудь материал коллайдера, но нужного как вы понимаете нет, я много как изголялся но шар не прогибался.

Вопросы следующие:

- Можно ли сделать это только с помощью Unity? Если да, то через какой компонент? Или через скрипт? Если скрипт, то в какую сторону гулить?
- Если только через Unity не получится,что нужно сделать? Создать модель в 3D редакторе? Что нужно учесть?
- Такие деформации делаются через анимацию, или через родные свойства объекта?

Comment: Можно, но сложно. Я посмотрел поверхностно, в принципе гуглить можно в сторону `unity deformation mesh` и найти [что-то вроде этого](http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/mesh-deformation/) или же гуглить в сторону работы с mesh на уровне кода `unity procedural mesh`, но это сверхсложный уровень.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что вы хотите получить регулируется не материалом коллайдера для модели. Материал коллайдера отвечает за то, как он будет взаимодействовать с другими коллайдерами.

Ваш вопрос лежит в области изменения вершин меша. Могу посоветовать вам прочитать три статьи на хабре, посвящённые этому, как раз сможете более полно понимать суть вопроса.

[Часть 1 — Генерация меша с помощью карты высот](https://habr.com/post/328498/)
[Часть 2 — Деформация меша с помощью карты высот](https://habr.com/post/328564/)
[Часть 3 — Деформация меша, основанная на коллизиях](https://habr.com/post/329146/)